# Design pattern to reduce redundancy

Tags: java

I am currently designing a class which heavily makes use of reflection by manipulating the declared fields. Hence, a lot of methods have something in common in terms of their body, which is (hopefully) illustrated by this java code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class foo {
    public void foo1(/* arguments1 */) {
        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff using arguments1
        }
    }

    public void foo2(/* arguments2 */) {
        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff using arguments2
        }
    }

    public void foo3(/* arguments3 */) {
        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff using arguments3
        }
    }

    //and so on...
}
```

Depending on how many methods this class will finally contain, could this be considered a design flaw? If I want to use `getFields()` instead of `getDeclaredFields()` for example, I would need to replace every occurrence of `getDeclaredFields()`. This does not sound like good programming practice to me. In my case this might not be a very realistic scenario, but for the sake of interest I would like to know if there is a design pattern or a concept which tackles this problem.

**[EDIT]**

To avoid additional misunderstandings: The operations inside the loop depend on the arguments given by foo1, foo2 etc.. and those arguments are not always the same for each method. I illustrated this fact poorly, sry. I improved the given code to demonstrate it better.

Comment: Your edit makes this much harder to solve. To remove redundancy, we must know what patterns are invariant, and you're telling us that things are changing but not giving us hint as to how they're changing.

Comment: Well, the only part which is invariant is the fact that every method visits each declared field and does "something" with it using the corresponding arguments. What the method actually does is variant. Same goes for the arguments. Honestly, I don't know how to illustrate it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to define an interface for the body of the loop:

```
interface FieldOperation {
    void doSomeStuff(Field f);
}
```

Then you can write a single looping method in place of `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`:

```
public void foo(/* arguments */, FieldOperation op) {
    for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        op.doSomeStuff(f);
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate several `FieldOperation` objects:

```
FieldOperation foo1Operation = new FieldOperation() {
    void doSomeStuff(Field f) {
        // do some stuff that used to be in foo1()
    }
}
// etc.
```

This scales nicely and separates the logic of which fields to access from the operation that you want to do on each field.

**EDIT** If each `foo*` requires a different set of arguments, I'd suggest packaging them up as classes:

```
class Foo1Args { . . . }
class Foo2Args { . . . }
class Foo3Args { . . . }
```

Then you can make your interface generic:

```
interface FieldOperation<T> {
    void doSomeStuff(Field f, T args);
}
```

and define `foo` to be a generic method:

```
public <T> void foo(T args, FieldOperation<T> op) {
    for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        op.doSomeStuff(f, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Unfortunately the operations inside the loop depend  on the arguments given by foo1, foo2... And those arguments are not always the same for every method. Maybe i should have pointed that out better, sry.

Comment: In that case, there's probably nothing you can do.

Comment: @user1658887 - If the arguments have a standard form (the same for all `foo`s), then you can define the interface accordingly. Alternatively, you can package the args as a class and make the interface generic.

Comment: @user1658887 I added some sample code showing an outline of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the logic to find the fields, you can externalize it to a separate method or field:

```
public class foo {
    private final Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    public void foo1(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : fields) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    public void foo2(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : fields) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    public void foo3(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : fields) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought of this possibility. Funny side effect here: Since the "fields" field is most likely not of interest for those methods you have to filter it out in every loop. Anyways, this still seems to be the best solution in my case because I can externalize the logic to a method (as you suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new field that you need to need to filter from your other methods, why not create a method to get the fields:

```
public class foo {
    private Field[] getDeclaredFields() { 
        return getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }

    public void foo1(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    public void foo2(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    public void foo3(/* arguments */) {
        for (Field f : getDeclaredFields()) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I am currently using as pointed out one post above. However, I was more interested in reusing and externalizing the "field enumeration".